# Laravel redirecting image paths

Tags: php, laravel

My image paths are being redirected outside of public folder when using GET variables. Here is my rundown (any suggestions to improve this would be also appreciated, though not necessary:

Route:

```
Route::get('retailers/{country}', array(
    'as' => 'find-retailers',
    'uses' => 'SiteController@getRetailers')
);
```

Controller:

```
   public function getRetailers($country)
    {
     // Query Builder
    $locations = DB::table('retailers_listings')
        ->orderBy('country', 'asc')
        ->where('country', $country)
        ->get();

        return View::make('retailers.stores')
        ->with('retailers_listings', $locations);
    }
```

EDIT:

The above route and controller is what I use to handle the view stores.blade.php. Inside my views folder I have a sub directory called **retailers** which holds 2 views. **index.blade** and **stores.blade**.

```
/views
 /retailers
   index.blade.php
   stores.blade.php
```

Image paths working in index.blade.php like so:
`public/uploads/retailers/logos/image.png`

Image path not working in stores.blade.php like so:
`/public/retailers/uploads/retailers/logos/image.png`

It is loading the images from `public/retailers` folder when they should be loaded from `public`.

Comment: Your question is not clear, what redirect ? do you have problem with image path stored in your public folder or what, please clarify it.

Comment: You didn't even provide any image related example or use case with code.

Comment: My image paths are being redirected. My above question is as clear as I can get on the topic.

Comment: Image path can't redirect, anyways, how you are using images to show up on your site, provide any example where you are using image.

Comment: @SheikhHeera check edit. Hope that gives you a better idea.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If your image's path is `public/uploads/retailers/logos/image.png` then use `src` like this:

```
<img src="{{ asset('uploads/retailers/logos/image.png') }}" />
```

Comment: There are various image paths being called from fields in a table. Is it required of me to call all my images like this? As everything working fine in all other pages doing it traditionally.

Comment: Images stored in `public/..` folder should be used this way.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help! This works for me and will use this practise in the future.

Comment: +1 though I didn't down vote but always  try toprovide right information, anyways, You are welcome @Esotericist.

Comment: Works for me using <div style="background: url({{ asset('/profiles/profile1.jpg') }}) no-repeat;"></div> Thanks!